# RSA: Obtain private key exploiting badly generated public key

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, prime-numbers

I have to solve the following problem:

What I have:

- $n$, a 2048 bit number

What I need to find:

- $p$ and $q$ such that $n = p\cdot q$.

What I know:

- With $p_1$ the first half of $p$ and $p_2$ the second half, the same with $q_1$ and $q_2$:
  $$p_1 = q_2\ \text{ and }\ p_2 = q_1$$
- Therefore finding $p$ you could also find $q$ and vice-versa.
- The size of both $p$ and $q$ is 1024 bits.
- (obviously) everything assumed in RSA, such as $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

I have been attempting this problem for 6h and I'm *hopeless*, any help is thanked!

Comment: Hint to get started: Assume that "halves" is about the binary representation of $p$ and $q$. Find the number of bits in $p_1$ and $p_2$, note that $b$. Translate _“$p_1$ the first half of $p$ and $p_2$ the second half”_ into a single equation involving $b$, $p$, $p_1$, $p_2$. Same with $q$. Now what is $n$ as a function of $b$, $p_1$, $p_2$? Now try to solve for $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: Further hint (assuming you need it): to start solving for $p_1, p_2$, first try to recover $p_1 \times p_2$.  Once you have that, try to recover $p_1 + p_2$.